# order of c++ range based iterations of std::vector

Tags: c++, iterator, range, stdvector

I use a range based c++ iterator on a `std::vector` and I wanted to ask **if the scan order
is guaranteed to be the "natural" order of the elements in the vector**? When I tried it out with the following program I see it is, but I'm not sure it is guaranteed to always behave the same?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> numbers{9,8,7,6,5};
    for (auto number : numbers)
    {
        std::cout << number << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it I get the expected order:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
$ ./main
9 8 7 6 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range based loops are just a shortcut to the traditional `for (auto it=numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)` loop. The order is always from `begin` to `end`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's guaranteed. The range-based for loop always uses the iterators' prefix operator `++` and goes from begin to end.

Technicalities follow:

The range-based for loop

```
for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
```

is defined in the standard to be equivalent to this code:

```
{
  auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
  auto __begin = begin-expr ;
  auto __end = end-expr ;
  for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

where `begin-expr` and `end-expr` depend on the type being iterated over:

- For a plain C array `a[n]`, it's `a` and `a + n`.
- For a class object `c` which defines members `begin` and `end` (such as your `std::vector`), it's `c.begin()` and `c.end()`.
- Otherwise for an object `r`, it's ADL lookup of `begin(r)` and `end(r)`.